# How can I reproduce the choppy synth in "Come on Home" by Franz Ferdinand?

Tags: synthesizer

I want to prepare a base so we can play with my band a cover of this song:

I have a Korg R3 and Garageband.

Can you hear the "choppy" synth at the beginning?
How could I reproduce it well?
Which kind of sound / effect should I choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rythmic effect can be achieved by filtering some signal through a lowpass VCF (12 dB/8ve, little resonance) heavily modulated (~ 800 Hz down to 20 Hz) by a sawtooth LFO. That gives the basic "choppy" thing. Then you can try all kinds of stuff to get the actual sound; perhaps start with a PWM-square or sawtooth VCO and ring-modulate it with a triangle after the VCF, then a fixed bandpass filter with a little saturation.

Comment: That sounds so tron! :D

I hope I can hack my way through finding this in garageband or logic or anything!
I'll keep you posted and then vote for answer: thanks for now.

Comment: My money is on the signal being distorted *before* it gets to the filter, and in fact, my money is on the signal being a power chord played through the same amp, with the exact same configuration as the "main" guitar part.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a standard power chord played on guitar, possibly looped, then fed through a low pass VCF with some resonance, modulated by a sawtooth LFO.
Some additional equalizing should give you a really close approximation.

Comment: Definitely a possibility; at any rate the sound blends in very well with all the guitars on the album – though, there are quite a few definitive keyboards on that track. You don't have a reference that it was done this way in the original?

Comment: Not at all, I'm sorry. 
I *did* feed my guitar through the same configuration on a track I cut a long time ago, and it sounded like the OP's video :)